# React Native JSI: How to call expose a promised function from native to javascript

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-jsi

I need to use my custom native fetch function from javascript code on my React Native iOS app and it must be asynchronous and works the same as standard one. I want to implement it with React Native JSI so how to expose asynchronous function to javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose an asynchronous function from native to javascript you can use `Promise` object from the React Native runtime and use its constructor to build the promise with your code. For instance, there is implementation of 'nativeFetch' function with `NSURLSession`:

**AppDelegate.mm**

```cpp
#include <jsi/jsi.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge+Private.h>

using namespace facebook::jsi;
using namespace std;

void installNativeFetch(Runtime& runtime) {
  auto nativeFetch = Function::createFromHostFunction(runtime,
                                                      PropNameID::forAscii(runtime, "nativeFetch"),
                                                      1,
                                                      [](Runtime &runtime, const Value &thisValue, const Value *args, size_t count) -> Value {
    const string strURL = args[0].asString(runtime).utf8(runtime);
    
    // Get global Promise
    auto promise = runtime.global().getPropertyAsFunction(runtime, "Promise");
    return promise.callAsConstructor(runtime, Function::createFromHostFunction(runtime,
                                                                               PropNameID::forAscii(runtime, "executor"),
                                                                               2,
                                                                               [strURL](Runtime &runtime, const Value &thisValue, const Value *args, size_t) -> Value {
      auto resolve = make_shared<Value>(runtime, args[0]);
      auto reject = make_shared<Value>(runtime, args[1]);
      
      NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:strURL.c_str()]];
      NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error) {
        if (error != nil) {
          // Reject
          auto value = Value(runtime, String::createFromUtf8(runtime, error.localizedDescription.UTF8String));
          reject->asObject(runtime).asFunction(runtime).call(runtime, move(value));
        }
        else {
          auto result = Object(runtime);
          int statusCode = (int)((NSHTTPURLResponse*)response).statusCode;
          result.setProperty(runtime, "statusCode", statusCode);
          result.setProperty(runtime, "statusText", String::createFromUtf8(runtime, [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode].UTF8String));
          
          // Resolve
          resolve->asObject(runtime).asFunction(runtime).call(runtime, move(result));
        }
      }];
      [task resume];
      return {};
    }));
  });
  
  // Bind our function with the javascript runtime global object
  runtime.global().setProperty(runtime, "nativeFetch", nativeFetch);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

  ...

  // Runtime notification
  [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:RCTJavaScriptDidLoadNotification object:nil queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification) {
    // Get runtime
    RCTCxxBridge* cxxbridge = (RCTCxxBridge*)notification.userInfo[@"bridge"];
    if (cxxbridge.runtime) {
      Runtime& runtime = *(Runtime*)cxxbridge.runtime;
      
      installNativeFetch(runtime);
    }
  }];
  
  return YES;
}
```

**App.js**

```js
async function get(url) {
    try {
        const result = await nativeFetch(url);
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
}

...

get('https://unknown');
get('https://google.com');
```

Outputs:

```sh
{ statusCode: 200, statusText: 'no error' }
Error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

> Note: Since the sample uses JSI for synchronous native methods access, remote debugging (e.g. with Chrome) is no longer possible. Instead, you should use Flipper for debugging your JS code.